# Sourcecode of older jpedal versions (4.75 and 4.76)

Tags: java, pdf, jpedal

I am currently tracking a bug in the lgpl version of [jpedal](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jpedal/). It would help tremendously  if somebody of you still has (and could supply) the sourcecode of the jpedal version `4.75` and `4.76`.

I know that version `4.92` is available on sourceforge however to isolate the problem I need the source of those two versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for reference, thanks to the world wide web I was able to get the source for version 4.75 and thus I was quickly able to locate the source of the problem.

If somebody needs it, too: [4.75b25](https://github.com/miho/VRL-Studio/blob/master/VRL-Studio/lib/jpedal/jpedal_lgpl_src.zip)